# Specifying & operating a TRIAC with a low voltage load

Tags: arduino, triac, low-voltage

I am looking to do a circuit to switch a 12 VAC of a device to the ground.
I intend to use a microcontroller to drive the TRIAC.
The goal here is only to short the 12 VAC of a device to its ground.
What kind of TRIAC do I need to do that ?

Comment: What is the device, and why do you want to 'short' the 12VAC to ground?

Comment: This needs more info, also are you aware that a turned-on triac will not be a short, but will have some voltage across it which may not be negligible here?

Comment: I removed the references to an Arduino as the question is related to TRIACs and to any microcontroller. Questions which reference Arduinos are likely to get moved to the Arduino page - which would be incorrect in this case. You should provide a circuit diagram and explain what you are tring to achieve - ie "shorting" an AC source is probably not exactly what you want to do. Also voltage and current requirements are needed.

Comment: To control a TRIAC with a microcontroller you need to drive its gate at a specified voltage and current level. It is likely to be easier/better to use a TRIAC driver opto-coupler such as a MOC3023 [**data sheet here**](http://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS-70-99-0019/MOC302X%20series%20201606.pdf).(The 3023 needs the lowest drive current of the 302x series).